# Wordpress plugin updates break site when pushed

Tags: wordpress, git, vagrant, wsod

I'm having some trouble updating the plugins on a wordpress website. It's all my fault for waiting too long to update them, and now pushing the updates with git breaks the site (the development site is ok, only the staging site that I've pushed to breaks). I tried updating everything manually, and will composer, but both methods don't last - the plugins revert back to their previous version with subsequent git pushes.

Is there any way to update these plugins now, barring deleting them all and starting again (which I'm not entirely opposed to at this point). The site doesn't get too much traffic, but solutions with minimal downtime are preferable.

This is the error I'm seeing on the broken site:

"The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

Here's the error from the terminal:

```
PHP Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/quorumhubnu.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258
PHP Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
Warning:
include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory in
/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
'/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-
more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion
(include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-
stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-
objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/w
p/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/
php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins
/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262
fatal: [107.170.41.149]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["wp", "option", "get", "template_root"], "delta": "0:00:00.558022", "end": "2020-09-11 16:11:42.260885", "failed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "rc": 0, "start": "2020-09-11 16:11:41.702863", "stderr": "PHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nWarning: include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nPHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nWarning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258\nPHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262\nWarning: include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262\nPHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262\nWarning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "stderr_lines": ["PHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "Warning: include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/classes/class.alm-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 258", "PHP Warning:  include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "Warning: include_once(/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262", "Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/integration/elementor/elementor.php' for inclusion (include_path='phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:phar:///usr/bin/wp/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/mysite.com/releases/20200911161105/web/app/plugins/ajax-load-more/ajax-load-more.php on line 262"], "stdout": "/themes", "stdout_lines": ["/themes"]}
```

(Yes, I know it's looking for a file it can't find.)

I'm using:
ansible 2.3
python version = 2.7.15
PHP 7.2.19
vagrant 2.2.5

Let me know if there's any important information I forgot to include.

Edit: I should add that this may be a vagrant related issue. If there are any vagrant users out there, let me know what you think!

Comment: Besides the fact you actually use git, ansible, python, vagrant.... as tools in your dev/deployment, can you clarify what theses tags are for in this case ? The tags should reflect the actual content of your question (which is entirely WordPress here IMO) and not everything you can think of that goes around it. Please take some time to think about it then edit your question and remove the irrelevant ones. As an example, I'm 100% sure ansible can be removed without loosing any relevant audience to help you out. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Zeitounator. While that's a good point in most cases, in this case I'm a little too far from the answer to rule out the possibility of this being an issue with ansible. After all, everything was working until I deployed the changes to staging. Maybe your critique is that I should spell out all the technologies that could be causing the problem, instead of giving it an honorable mention just in case? Hopefully if the tag is wrong or too broad, that audience won't waste too much time on it!

Comment: I would delete the ajax-load-more plugin and see if that takes care of things. Reinstall it later if needed. Also, are any unused plugins removed? And any third party (i.e. not from the WordPress plugin library) plugins up to date? I've had both be the culprit of "updates broke the site".